# Is ubuntu gamepack worth it? Compared to kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, lenovo, games, easytether

I'm a gamer but on my PC with kubuntu 18.04 lts kernel 5.4 I cant get tethering to work. The libraries and programs I need are said to be on this os. Is it wise to grab this os and use it since my method of downloading is to my phone and then transferring files to PC via mtp?
So many problems with easy tether.

To save forum space would it be wise to install the grub 2 efi bootloader to the iso? It only boots via legacy for me.

My system is the Lenovo thinkcentre m73 10ax.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 has two kernel options; neither of which is 5.4.  Ubuntu gamepack isn't Ubuntu, read the site that it comes from (ualinux.com) and it calls it UALinux based on Ubuntu; but it is not Ubuntu, nor an official flavor of Ubuntu; thus is off-topic here (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Ubuntu is downloaded from ubuntu.com; even ubuntu flavors com from ubuntu.com too (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) ; UALinux Gamepack (with ubuntu in half-invisible lettering) however comes from ualinux.com which should be a clue even if you didn't read the small print.

Comment: I upgraded the kernel to 5.4 and thank you for letting me know it's not ubuntu. I only assumed that because it has everything ubuntu in it. All they did was add programs. Should I delete question?

Comment: Also I decided to dual boot and use kubuntu's version of grub.

Comment: Kubuntu is an official flavor of Ubuntu and thus on-topic for this site, Ubuntu gamepack which is UAlinux is not Ubuntu, thus off-topic on this and most Ubuntu support sites, thus you'll have to deal with problems in the much smaller UA Linux community. Kubuntu doesn't have it's own version of grub; it uses the Ubuntu packaged version (you may be talking about a wallpaper or gui picture displaying on grub but that can be any appropriate picture). I actually see little on-topic question here sorry since heading & most of text is about off-topic detail (non-ubuntu product)